# Cancelling matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm solving a exercise, and the following question has arisen:

> Let $A,B,C$ be non-zero matrices, if $AB=CB$ then is $A=C?$

I already have a partial solution when $A,B,C$ are square matrices and $B$ is invertible: in this case $A=CBB^{-1}=CI_n=C$.

This result is valid in general case? (I mean, when the matrices are arbitrary)

Thanks!

Comment: Clearly not, take $B=0$. You need $B$ to have 'full' range space.

Comment: No, this is only true if there is another matrix $D$ such that $BD = I_n$, which is equivalent to saying that $B$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, the answer is "no, not in the general case".

But you should be able to prove more than that, namely that $B$ can be canceled (on the right, in the sense that $AB=CB\Rightarrow A=C$ for *all* $A$ and $C$ of the right width) exactly when its rank equals its height. For a square $B$ this is exactly when it is invertible.

Comment: so, when the $B$ matrix can be canceled? What the criterium for that?

Comment: @DiegoMath: I don't understand that question -- it seems to ask for exactly what I explain here.

Comment: The answer is: $B$ can be canceled when its rank equal its height?

Comment: @DiegoMath: Yes. (On the right. For cancellation on the left, you of course need the rank to equal its _width_ instead).

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider
$$
A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 0  \\
   0 & { - 1}  \\
\end{array}} \right),
$$

$$
B = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 0  \\
   0 & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right),
$$

$$
C = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 0  \\
   0 & 1  \\
\end{array}} \right),
$$
then $AB=CB$ but $A\ne C$.